# Calculating the difference in percentage of two HTML files

Tags: php, html, diff, levenshtein-distance

I'm writing a tool in php which compares HTML files and shows the differences. Now I'm looking for an efficient way to calculate the difference in percentage between two HTML files. These files can be arbitrary long (the files I have can be as long as 300000 characters).

After some research I stumbled upon the Levensthein distance which is an algorithm of O(n*m) and requires space O(n*m): the php version can only support up to 255 characters and my own implementation of O(n) space, was too slow.
After that, I tried the php function similar_text, but that algorithm is also too slow for very large HTML files.

So now I'm looking for another, more efficient algorithm to compare HTML files. An approximation algorithm is also fine. Could anyone give me some advice on how to do this?

Comment: Do you need to compare files or their content? If you strip_tags the files would be much shorter.

Comment: I guess it depends what differences you are checking? e.g. Does whitespace count etc?

Comment: Why can't you run diff and use its output?

Comment: @Devos50:  you didn't respond to my question for almost a year.  OK, some new details: Smart Differencer (see my bio) does Levenstein distance on the *code structure* (ignoring irrelevant stuf like whitespace), not characters, so it scales much better. You could use its output to compute your % difference in a more meaningful way than pure diff.  Yes, there is one for diffing HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup the xdiff extension:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-file-diff.php

Then get the diff of the two files, and based on that diff you can easily come with the percentage.

Example:

- First File A: 400 words
- Second File B: 400 words

Diff Results: 200 words diff from A to B

That would give you a 50% similarity.